# Lighthouse Performance score is Zero on localhost, but when deployed to external webhost I get 30

Tags: vue.js, npm, lighthouse, web-performance

I am auditing my website locally and lighthouse is constantly showing the performance to be 0, no matter what improvements I make, not really sure what's the issue there, because the same codebase when I deploy to an external webhost (ex: firebase) I am seeing correct score reflecting the improvements I am making. I am using npm to serve the website locally, I am suspecting some configuration there got messed up, because the performance is still 0 even when I create a brand new skeleton website.
Has anyone faced similar issue or know of fix? Thanks!

Comment: How are you running Lighthouse?

Comment: I am running it from audit tab in developer tools.